Controls on screen don't get triggered
Problem
I have a text entry field, and a button on a new screen in a MAUI Android app. I have breakpoints in the debugger, but nothing is happening when I click on these  controls. No text shows in the text field, and the breakpoint is not hit for the button.
What I've tried: I've tried minimizing the code. I have double checked the variable names, the bindings, etc. Tried doing manual focus/unfocus. I have been stuck on this for days. What else am I missing??
Screen.xaml:
    <Grid
        Grid.Row="2"
        Padding="10,0"
        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Gray1}"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <controls:CustomEntry
            x:Name="SecurityQuestionAnswer"
            Grid.Row="0"
            FontSize="14"
            HeightRequest="45"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            Keyboard="Default"
            Text="{Binding SecurityQuestionAnswer}"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
        <Entry
            x:Name="SecurityQuestionAnswer"
            Placeholder="Type answer here..."
            IsEnabled="True"
            IsVisible="True"
            Text="{Binding SecurityQuestionAnswer}"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            />
    </Grid>
    <!--  Submit Button Section  -->
    <Button
        x:Name="btnSubmitSecurityQuestionButton"
        Grid.Row="3"
        Margin="50,10"
        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Green1}"
        Command="{Binding SubmitAnswerCommand}"
        FontSize="14"
        HeightRequest="55"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        Text="Submit"
        TextColor="{StaticResource White}"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        WidthRequest="180" />

Screen.xaml.cs:
    public ForgotPasswordSecurityQuestionsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = VM = new ForgotPasswordSecurityQuestionsPageViewModel(this.Navigation);
    }

ScreenViewModel.cs:
    public class ForgotPasswordSecurityQuestionsPageViewModel :BaseViewModel
    {
        #region Constructor
                public ForgotPasswordSecurityQuestionsPageViewModel(INavigation nav)
        {
            try
            {
                Navigation = nav;
                SubmitAnswerCommand = new Command(SubmitAsync);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)           {    Console.WriteLine(ex);  }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Command
        public Command SubmitAnswerCommand { get; set;}
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        private string _SecurityQuestionAnswer;
        public string SecurityQuestionAnswer
        {
            get { return _SecurityQuestionAnswer; }
            set
            {
                if (_SecurityQuestionAnswer != value)
                {
                    _SecurityQuestionAnswer = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("SecurityQuestionAnswer");
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Methods
        private async void SubmitAsync(object obj)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SecurityQuestionAnswer))
            {     
                 await _navigationService.Navigate<ResetPasswordViewModel, int>(securityQuestionNavigationParam.UserID);
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }


What .NET version do you use?

No text shows in the text field Do you mean even cannot type in an Entry?

@LiqunShen-MSFT Correct, I cant even type in an Entry

I'm using .NET 8

I think more relevant code should be included in your post as I cannot reproduce the issue based on your code. For example, how do you use or navigate to this page? What is about the this.Navigation in the page? It's really weird that even cannot type in an Entry.

The CustomEntry and Entry share the same name of SecurityQuestionAnswer, which will cause an error. And the two Entries are overlapped in the Grid Layout.
